# mysql which table is faster: with more rows or columns?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

What of this mysql tables better for usage in mysql SELECT(if result of data > 10 000 rows) and for while(result of data)

Example:

this:

```
id | cost 1 | cost 2 | cost 3 | cost 4 | cost 5 |
 1 |  10    |  11    |   12   |  13    |    14  |
```

or this:

```
id | cost | costNumber
 1 |  10  |      1
 2 |  11  |      2
 3 |  12  |      3
 4 |  13  |      4
 5 |  14  |      5
```

Who know or tested, help ples!

Comment: Only one of these forms is [correctly normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Use it. If there ever is a case where the denormalized table is 'better' or 'faster' it should *only* be used after thorough analysis and specific usage benchmarks - which is way above the level (or need) of this question. (Also, do note these tables *do not represent the same thing*.)

Comment: @user2864740 What form first or second is correctly normalized? pls

Comment: I've provided the link above. However, `col1.. col2.. col3` naming usually indicates a flaw with the relational design if the columns cannot be given specific *non-indexed* names.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience 2nd table is always better.